# Creating New Windows Server 2012 r2 Vagrant Box

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-server-2012-r2, packer

I'm trying to create a Windows Server 2012 R2 Vagrant box from a VirtualBox instance. Most of the tutorials I follow just say to run

`vagrant package --base packer-virtualbox-iso-1450701695 --output windows-2012r2.box`

and then run

`vagrant box add windows-2012r2 windows-2012r2.box`

but this results in

```
==> box: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> box: Adding box 'windows-2012r2' (v0) for provider:
    box: Unpacking necessary files from: file://E:/VirtualBox%20VMs/windows-2012r2.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 62.0M/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The "metadata.json" file for the box 'windows-2012r2' was not found.
Boxes require this file in order for Vagrant to determine the
provider it was made for. If you made the box, please add a
"metadata.json" file to it. If someone else made the box, please
notify the box creator that the box is corrupt. Documentation for
box file format can be found at the URL below:
```

Any suggestions? Also I'm trying to do this because I need to run a Powershell command on the box before saving it, so a pointer to how I'd be able to update and save an existing vagrant box so that it can be reused would be good too.

Comment: whats weird is the empty value on `'windows-2012r2' (v0) for provider:` do you have `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` variable set ? can you run `vagrant box add windows-2012r2 windows-2012r2.box --provider virtualbox`

Comment: I ran that command but got the same message, just with the provider listed as virtualbox.